# Short-circuit evaluation in RavenDB

Tags: c#, full-text-search, ravendb

Does ravenDB automatically Short-circuit queries ?
If not is there a way to achieve this.

**Example:**
I search in my database using a full text search. But this search has other fields which should meet specific values. So how would I prioritize this other fields first before doing the expensive full text search.

Atm my query looks something like this:

```
condition1 AND condition2 AND FTS
```

I'm using Raven embedded client on the .Net 4.5 framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Lucene, the index implementation under the hood, will sometimes re-arrange your query on a best-effort basis. But there's no short-circuit behavior available, and no way to achieve that.

Your assumption of full-text search being "expensive" is wrong. Phrase searches, and sometimes wildcard/prefix queries may be a bit costlier to perform due to large lists of terms to enumerate or the requirement to load position data, but all queries in RavenDB are practically a Lucene query so both `condition1` and `FTS` in your query are practically the same.

HTH